# How to get a list from an iterator

Tags: c++

How can I get a list from an iterator ?

```
std::list<int> list;
auto it1 = list.insert(list.end(), 1);
auto it2 = list.insert(list.end(), 2);
auto it3 = list.insert(list.end(), 3);
auto it4 = list.insert(list.end(), 4);
auto it5 = list.insert(list.end(), 5);

list.erase(it3);
```

In included code, I am able to erase `it3` from the list.
What if I know only an iterator, can an iterator erase itself from the list without having the list variable ?

```
//Something like that
it2.list.erase(it2);
```

Comment: No it can't. Neither does it makes sense to do so.

Comment: I highly recommend not naming a variable the same name as the structure.  Could get very confusing.

Comment: An iterator points to an element in a list.  You can't get the parent structure from an element in the list.

Comment: A `std::list<int>::iterator` will work for any `std::list<int>`.  You can't get which list it belongs to.

Comment: It's sort of an interesting point, though, because in the typical C implementation all you need is a pointer to a single node in order to do list splicing, and that's kind of half the power of it. I'd never really considered how we've sacrificed that in `std::list`. Mind you, it's not as if `std::list` set out to be a direct replacement for all of that very specific functionality.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is the difference of viewing a linked list as the union of individual nodes, as opposed to considering them as components of the same structure. It's a trade-off for sure, but it made maintaining invariants possible

Comment: @PasserBy: Indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the list from an iterator, you can obtain the iterator from the list. The [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) container has an [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) member function, iterator does not, so no, it can not erase itself. If you know the iterator, supply it to the list's `erase` function. As pointed out in the comments you should not name your variable `list`, especially if you have `using namespace std;` statement somewhere in your code which is also to be avoided.

Comment: Yeah, i did a quick example and did not think about same names :-)

Answer (score 2):

Technically it is possible to erase element in [Doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) and update neighboring nodes links after erasure. But `std::list` also maintains it's [size()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size), which must run in O(1) since C++11. So it is impossible to update the list size without accessing list itself.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) `std::list::iterator` satisfies concept [`BidirectionalIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) so as you can see there neither such concept not it's ancestors have such functionality to get container it belongs to.